# How to use H.264 encoding for NoMachine on Linux

Tags: archlinux, nomachine-nx, nomachine

I am running NoMachine server on Arch Linux and connecting it from NoMachine client on Windows10. I have set the encoding H.264 in server preference but it always picks up VP8 irrespective of my settings.

How can i enable H264 encoding on server and decoding in client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H.264 will be used by default if:
(i) the hardware  or software H.264 encoder is available on server-side
and
(ii) the HW or SW H.264 decoder is present on client-side.

If neither the server nor any of the clients support H.264, VP8 will be used as a fallback.

So you should make sure  you have the appropriate libraries built on the server side if you are using the free version. The free version doesn't ship them.

Comment: I did exactly what you have described. I did not know the fact that I have to compile the codecs provided by nomachine. After I compiled codecs nomachine used H264 and I am observing a performance boost.